# How accurate is my understanding of "saber (de)" and "conocer"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones

I'm trying to understand the details and differences between *saber*, *saber de*, and *conocer* a little bit better.

Here's my understanding of what these words mean in various contexts. Are these translations all accurate? Which ones could be improved and how?

- A person

  - **Sé a David.** *Not used.*
  - **Sé de David.** I'm knowledgeable about David (but I haven't necessarily met him).
  - **Conozco a David.** I've met David; David is an acquaintance of mine.
- A place

  - **Sé Colorado.** *Not used.*
  - **Sé de Colorado.** I know a lot of things about Colorado (but I haven't necessarily been there).
  - **Conozco Colorado.** Colorado is a familiar place; I've probably been there.
- A topic

  - **Sé matemáticas.** I know the entirety of mathematics (which is impossible).
  - **Sé de matemáticas.** I know a lot of mathematics; I'm knowledgeable about mathematics.
  - **Conozco matemáticas.** I've seen a lot of mathematics before; seeing or hearing about mathematics is a familiar experience (but I don't necessarily understand anything about mathematics.)
- A language

  - **Sé español.** I can speak Spanish; I have the knowledge and skills needed to speak Spanish.
  - **Sé de español.** I'm knowledgeable about the Spanish language (but I'm not necessarily able to speak it).
  - **Conozco español.** Spanish is a familiar language; I've had a lot of exposure to Spanish (but I don't necessarily have any knowledge about Spanish).
- An action

  - **Sé nadar.** I can swim; I know how to swim.
  - **Sé de nadar.** I know various things about swimming.
  - **Conozco nadar.** (I'm not sure what this would mean. I know what it's like to swim? I've seen a lot of swimming happen?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sé matemáticas* doesn't mean you know the entirety of mathematics; it's perfectly OK to use it.

*Sé de matemáticas* and *Sé de nadar* both sound a bit off; with a quantifier (*Sé algo de matemáticas*, *Sé bastante de nadar*) it might be better. In any case, *saber de* doesn't necessarily mean you know things; it often means just that you've heard of them or read about them, maybe with a bit more certainty than mere hearsay.

*Conozco matemáticas* sounds positively weird, as does *Conozco español*. In general I'd say *conocer* goes with people and places, not with skills. And it never goes with an infinitive: *Conozco nadar* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Although, adding an article makes more sense: *conozco las matemáticas* (= some of it); *conozco el español* (= not much but it rings a bell)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for all the sentences marked "not used."

Some of the other sentences are okay theoretically, but sound weird to my ear.

The following work great:

> *Sé algo/un poco/mucho acerca de* (topic) OR *Sé algo/un poco/mucho sobre* (topic, e.g. *las matemáticas, la economía*)
>
> *Conozco a* (person); *conozco* (place)
>
> *¿Sabes* (verb, e.g. *hablar español, nadar*)?

For a couple of your sentences, I'll suggest some more natural equivalents:

> No one knows everything there is to know about mathematics: *Nadie domina las matemáticas completamente*
>
> I was exposed to Spanish where I lived as a child: *Se oía frecuentemente el español donde yo vivía de pequeño*