# ¿"Saber" una palabra o "conocer" una palabra?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos

Si quiero decir "estoy familiarizado con [una palabra]" o "sé lo que significa [una palabra]", ¿debo decir "**conozco** esta palabra" or "**sé** esta palabra"?

Comment: I would go with "Conocer". I left an answer in a very similar question: [In this situation, would “saber de” or “conocer” be the better option?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10546/5481). In this context "to know" is "conocer", because "saber (de)" has the connotation of "To be aware of". You could alse check [How accurate is my understanding of “saber (de)” and “conocer”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20774/5481) and [When saber and conocer seem to overlap](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34991/5481)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How accurate is my understanding of "saber (de)" and "conocer"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20774/how-accurate-is-my-understanding-of-saber-de-and-conocer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Saber* is used most often to state that a person knows "how to do something".

Example: *Sabe coser, escribir, enseñar etc.*

Conocer is used to say someone knows something about something or someone.

Example: *Conoce la letra de esta canción, o conoce la canción, o conoce a una persona etc.*

You can use *saber* in the subjunctive mood. For example, A says, *"¿Dónde está José?* B says, *"Que yo sepa, está en su dormitorio."* = "As far as I know, he is in his room."

Answer (score 1):

Exposición ¿"Saber" una palabra o "conocer" una palabra?

---

Para no confundirse, ya que de lo contrario nos llevaría a exposiciones más complicadas de la utilización de los términos dentro de la lengua, existe una forma simple y fácil que puedes utilizar en cualquier ocasión.

Responda directamente con el mismo verbo con que le preguntan;

- ¿ Conoce la palabra "Mártir"?, Si ó No, conozco la palabra "Mártir", ...
- ¿ Sabes lo que significa la palabra "Mártir"?, Si ó No, se lo que significa "Mártir", ...
- ¿ Estas familiarizado con la palabra "Mártir"?, Si ó No, estoy familiarizado, ...

Espero te haya ayudado. Saludos. Diego M.